# Run Time Error 429 Active X Can't Create an Object, VBA to PPT

Tags: vba, templates, runtime-error, powerpoint

I am trying to create a powerpoint from an excel file using a company template. I can have it open a new powerpoint using the template and reference the correct slide layouts, but whenever I run my VBA I get a message

> Run Time Error 429 Active X Can't Create an Object

and I get a PPT in the template that just says **"tap to add first slide"**. How to I have it create the necessary object to proceed? The VBA uses both a sub procedure and a function, specified below. Thanks in advance!

```
Public Sub DevOppDeck()

    Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    'Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim DMAName As Variant
    Dim oSlides As Slides, oSlide As Slide

    'Creates a new powerpoint
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    ppApp.Visible = True
    ppApp.Activate


    'Takes user input and finds the DMA name

    userInput = InputBox("Please type in a DMA ID", "Create a Development Opportunity Deck")
    Worksheets("DMA Summary").Range("b4") = userInput

    Set findName = Worksheets("DMA Alignment").Range("C3:G217")
    DMAName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("DMA Alignment").Range("C3:G217"), _
                                                  Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DMA Summary").Range("B4"), Sheets("DMA Alignment").Range("C3:C217"), 0), _
                                                  Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("DMA Summary").Range("A5"), Sheets("DMA Alignment").Range("C3:G3"), 0))

    MsgBox ("Your DMA name is" & Space(1) & DMAName)

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add
    ppPres.ApplyTemplate ("C:\Users\rbiqs000\Documents\Custom Office Templates\RBI-template.potx")

    'Creates first slide in Title Slide latout from Company format

    Set oSlides = ActivePresentation.Slides
    Set oSlide = oSlides.AddSlide(1, GetLayout("Title Slide"))
    oSlide.Select

    'Updates Title and Date

    oSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DMAName & Space(1) & "Development Opportunity"
    'ppSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertDateTime (ppDateTimeMMMMdyyyy)


Public Function GetLayout( _
       LayoutName As String, _
       Optional ParentPresentation As Presentation = Nothing) As CustomLayout

    If ParentPresentation Is Nothing Then
        Set ParentPresentation = ActivePresentation
    End If

    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    For Each oLayout In ParentPresentation.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
        If oLayout.Name = LayoutName Then
            Set GetLayout = oLayout
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: on which line does error occur?

Comment: Comment out or delete "oSlide.Select". You never want to select anything unless it's absolutely necessary and in this case it's not. And it may well be the source of your error message.

Comment: The error seems to occur at Set oSlides = oSlides.AddSlide(1, GetLayout("Title Slide")) because it opens powerpoint with the template, but it just opens to a page that says "click to add slide" rather than adding the first slide, and i get this runtime error.